# Can anybody explain me the output of this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures, hoisting, shadowing

This is the code I am compiling.

```
var a = 10;
var c = 5;
b(40);

function b(x) {
  a(20);
  a=40;
  c=50;
  function a() { console.log(x);}  
}

console.log(a);
console.log(c);
```

Can you tell me the output and explain it?

Comment: This sounds like an assignment, which afaik shouldn't really be asked directly on SO. If you elaborate a bit, explain which parts you do and don't get, and maybe add a more specific question I'm sure people would be more willing to help :)

Comment: @Luca_Scorpion maybe he wants to ask why it's 40 10 50 and not 40 40 50?

Comment: @bestPlayer_xu Maybe? But that's exactly my point, the question is too vague to give a good answer imo.

Comment: @Luca_Scorpion Yeah. and the whole code doesn't make sense (to me)

Comment: @bestPlayer_xu yes that's what I'm asking.
Above code giving output : 40 10 50.
when I change the name of function "a", it's giving output : 40 40 50

Answer (score 2):

40
10
50

First b(40) will be executed. Then a(20) which will ignore the 20 and print the x (currently 40). Then a will be set to 40 and c to 50. Then both of them will be printed in line 12 and 13.

Comment: but the a used in b() isn't the same as the one as in the beginning (diff vars in diff functions)

Comment: Above code giving output : 40 10 50. when I change the name of function "a", it's giving output : 40 40 50

Answer (score 2):

40 10 50

the second one is 10 bc the a declared in b() isn't the same var as the one declared in the beginning (just execute the code).

Comment: Above code giving output : 40 10 50. when I change the name of function "a", it's giving output : 40 40 50

Comment: @AhmadSadiq no need to comment twice, you'll get one answer. actually, what's the issue?